# SSIS detecting changes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm currently learning my way around SSIS. And I'm looking for a better way to do something.

I'm loading data from an Oracle Database into SQL Server.

Oracle data is loaded, converted and sorted.
SQL Server data is also loaded, sorted.

These are then put into a Merge Join (Full Outer).

Then a conditional split occurs;
If the key is not in the source, but in the destination. The record is deleted (archived in fact).
If the key is in the source, but not the destination. The record is sent down the path to be inserted.

If they key exists in BOTH. Then it is sent down another path - herein lies my problem.

The table has 45 fields (not my decision!) and I am required to update the record if anything has changed. At present I use a Lookup, matching every field present with every other in a painstakingly awkward 'drag from left to right where names match'. It's also proving slow at times. Not to mention horrible to maintain.

In short: I'm looking for how would you properly check for differences between your source and your destination? When every field can change at any time.

Thanks.

Comment: I was under the impression SSIS can also UNION ALL?

Comment: Check this ... last post on thread https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic362765-148-1.aspx

Comment: I'll give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

This was spot on - Credit to Veljko89

Source: [Union All returns duplicates???](http://sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic362765-148-1.aspx)

Solution: 
You can do this is SSIS in two steps:

- Use a merge transform (as you mentioned above)
- Use a SORT transform, and sort the data on ContractID, making sure you check the box which says "Remove rows with duplicate sort values".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the previous comment is correct, does the table have a 'Last Updated Date' column where the date value will change every time the row is inserted/updated?  If yes, then your ETL only needs to pick off the rows where the 'Last Updated Date' is greater than the last time the ETL ran, then use the two column ID and 'Last Updated Date' instead of all 45 columns to JOIN the source and target.

The SSIS MERGE component is certainly appropriate for this situation, but fair warning it is very complex to use.  The Sentry One (former Pragmatic Works) third-party tool Task Factory ($$) also works and is less complex to use.

Good luck.